# Can we use custom UIView class for Launch Screen file?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Can we use custom UIView class for Launch Screen file ?

It is giving error like this : Illegal Configuration: Launch screens may not use instances of customclass of UIView.

[image]

Comment: Why are title and question wildly different?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something creative with the launch screen.  See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html